# Efficient Group Variable to Note When Values Fall Between Two Times

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains start and end time stamps, as well as a performance percentage. I'd like to calculate group statistics over hourly blocks, e.g. "the average performance for the midnight hour was x%."

My question is if there is a more efficient way to do this than a series of ifelse() statements.

```
# some sample data
pre.starting <- data.frame(starting = format(seq.POSIXt(from = 
as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), to = as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1), by = "5 min"),
              "%H:%M", tz="GMT"))

pre.ending <- data.frame(ending = pre.starting[seq(1, nrow(pre.starting), 
2), ])
ending2 <- pre.ending[-c(1), ]
starting2 <- data.frame(pre.starting = pre.starting[!(pre.starting$starting 
%in% pre.ending$ending),])

dataset <- data.frame(starting = starting2
                    , ending = ending2
                    , perct = rnorm(nrow(starting2), 0.5, 0.2))
```

For example, I could create hour blocks with code along the lines of the following:

```
dataset2 <- dataset %>% 
  mutate(hour = ifelse(starting >= 00:00 & ending < 01:00, 12
         , ifelse(starting >= 01:00 & ending < 02:00, 1
         , ifelse(starting >= 02:00 & ending < 03:00, 13)))
         ) %>% 
  group_by(hour) %>% 
  summarise(mean.perct = mean(perct, na.rm=T))
```

Is there a way to make this code more efficient, or improve beyond ifelse()?

Comment: Are there ever overlaps across two hour blocks in a single row?

Comment: If not, I think you can just group by `substr(dataset$pre.starting,1,2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cut` `ending` hour based on hourly interval after converting timestamps into `POSIXct` and then take `mean` for each hour.

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
  mutate_at(vars(pre.starting, ending), as.POSIXct, format = "%H:%M") %>%
  group_by(ending_hour = cut(ending, breaks = "1 hour")) %>%
  summarise(mean.perct = mean(perct, na.rm = TRUE))


#   ending_hour         mean.perct
#   <fct>                    <dbl>
# 1 2019-09-30 00:00:00      0.540
# 2 2019-09-30 01:00:00      0.450
# 3 2019-09-30 02:00:00      0.612
# 4 2019-09-30 03:00:00      0.470
# 5 2019-09-30 04:00:00      0.564
# 6 2019-09-30 05:00:00      0.437
# 7 2019-09-30 06:00:00      0.413
# 8 2019-09-30 07:00:00      0.397
# 9 2019-09-30 08:00:00      0.492
#10 2019-09-30 09:00:00      0.613
# … with 14 more rows
```